# Slim Framework + EasyPHP - Cannot access from local network

Tags: php, rest, slim, easyphp, local-network

its my first time with Slim, and i'm developing a REST Api.

When i access the URL using localhost (*http://localhost:8000/svn/sites/branches/project_name/public/api/cidades*), its works fine, but i need access by local network, by IP.

In this mode, my httpd.conf file is configured as follows: "Listen localhost:8000".

If i replace the "localhost" of the httpd.conf for "*" and try to access the same Url, but by IP, this error occurs:

```
**Not Found**

The requested URL /svn/sites/branches/project_name/public/api/cidades was not found on this server.
```

The .htaccess that is in the same folder of the index.php, has the content as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Someone can help me about what i need to configurate to access the api across the local network? Thank's.

Obs: I'm using EasyPHP on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried: `Listen 8000` ?

Comment: Yes, did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried to listen to the IP? Listen 192.168.0.x:8000 ?